# SQLite установка

Tags: c#, sqlite

С [system.data.sqlite.org](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki) скачал `Precompiled Binaries for 32-bit Windows (.NET Framework 4.5.1)` (x86) Установил.
Создал проект и добавил туда:

```
using System.Data.SQLite
```

SQLite подчеркивает. Искал в добавить -> ссылка, там нету.

Как уставить SQLite на VS 2013?

Видел, что добавляют dll. В готовых программах (Firefox) есть sqlite3.dll.

Comment: для установки нужно использовать Nuget package manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Устанавливайте через Nuget:

> Install-Package System.Data.SQLite

пляски с dll и тому подобные колдунства для VS 2013 выглядят чем-то вовсе древним

Comment: @DreamChild получается оно ставить для каждого проекта, то есть для нового нужно заново скачивать?

Comment: именно так. Однако вряд ли написание одной строки в консоли для нового проекта  можно считать чрезмерной платой за удобство добавления через nuget

Comment: @DreamChild, удобно. спасибо.